# Find and return all cycles given a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, cycle

I have an `int[,]` 2D array representing a house in a coordinate system. Each index is a type of enum representing building blocks, such as none=0, wall=1, stairs =2. The only part that I'm interested in this problem are the walls.

So the problem would be, given a 2D array of size NxM with marked slots like this;

```
//red circles represent 
array[i][k] == wall
```

[image]

I need to detect how many rooms there are in the grid in polynomial time.
So the result would be like this,

[image]

If rooms are found the desired algorithm would return an array of lists containing the positions of each wall.

So what I'm looking for is the function "findRooms"

```
struct position
{
  int x,y;
}

class Room
{
    List<position> walls;
    public Room(){};
}

class Floor
{

   int[,] grid;

   //
   // The function that's needed to be implemented
   //
   public List<Room> findRooms(int[,] grid)
   {
      // given a 2D grid returns a list of rooms. 

      return Rooms;
   }

}
```

I thought of representing the grid as a Graph and finding all the cycles in the graph, but I felt like that was over complicating things that they already were.

An example for this in use might be terraria's building system.

I would really appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at Flood fill algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: thanks, I'll try it and if I get it to working I'll accept your answer